# Ideal spots to farm minions

Tags: overlord

I'm kind of in a tight spot with Overlord at the moment.

I have to do a water-based dungeon, but my Blues count is awfully low.

Where can I farm each type of minion to get that count right back up when I need it? I know for browns you just massacre every sheep in sight, but where (in what areas, most particularly) do I go if I want Reds, Greens or Blues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured out, you can just go to the dungeon and spawn the beetles of the type you want minions of. You'll lose a lot of minions, but I managed to get about 40 when I lost 25 minions to the mobs. A good sacrifice if you ask me.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for me. I needed greens to kill a fire-immune flying Beholder. As far as I can tell nothing else works ( not reds, not spells, not blues, not browns... ).

Comment: In case someone else is doing this, in the dungeon I farmed greens by spawning Puffer Beetles, with an army of 10 blues, and maybe 30 reds.  The reds are anchored towards the door, with the blues anchored behind them.  I drew about 3 to 6 beetles at a time to firing range and battled them while they got flamed.  Blues were resurrection backup in case the reds aggro'd the beetles.

Answer (score 0):

There is totally no need to waste minions and lose valuable equipment (sometimes unique!). So, how does one farm them?

- Brown minions -- go and kill sheep near Mellow Hills. After you kill them all, quickly march back to the tower gate and return. Take a full-brown setup with you and help them with your highly-enchanted sword. That's very quick.
- Red -- go to the tower dungeon and kill dwarvern flamethrowers. Take red minions for distraction -- they don't take any damage from fire. If you are careful enough, you won't be damaged by the flames. They provide a lot of souls... But be careful when they explode.
- Green -- I didn't really need a lot of them, so I don't really know which way is the most effective, but that's the moment where bugs are really weak and minions are easily disposable (they typically don't use high-level equipment). Greens themselves are very situational because there is a limited number of spots on each enemy to latch on. And if they can't latch, they take damage, so don't take more than like 7 greens with you. If you need them to infuse weapons/armor (why?), bugs again...
- Blues are the same story. You won't need many of them in practice, but blue bugs are weak. You may also go with no minions and simply kill giant frogs yourself.

Bug farming isn't very effective with browns and reds, sheep/flamethrower farming is both quicker and easier.

It case you mess up, you may always put some blues at the entrance -- just don't let the enemy come to them. If you need resurrection, send just one and guard his path.

Answer (score 0):

I found that taking full horde of reds top the dungeons and kiting the beatles (if you pull them far enough from their starting positions and draw the reds far enough, the beatles will just sit in one place).

Using the guard marker for easy control of the minions is recommended.

You might lose one or two reds until you get used to the method, but it works quite well for me.